# Trying to disallow one page in subdirectory

Tags: seo, robots.txt, subdirectory

I am trying to disallow one page in subdirectory

I am using that robots.txt code is it

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow:
Disallow: /form.aspx
```

but the form.aspx is in processfolder and my url is showing like
www.yoursite.com/process/form.aspx

so how can I disallow `form.aspx` in `robots.txt`.

The format which is given above `robots.txt`: is it right?

please guide

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block `http://example.com/process/form.aspx` and allow everything else, you can use:

```
# robots.txt on <http://example.com/robots.txt>
User-agent: *
Disallow: /process/form.aspx
```

Note that this would also block URLs like `http://example.com/process/form.aspx.foo`, `http://example.com/process/form.aspx/bar`, etc.